# Display top tags & percentiles from additional Stack Exchange sites on Careers

Tags: feature-request, tags, jobs, network-profile

Are the "top tags & percentiles" from Stack Exchange sites other than Stack Overflow displayed in the Careers site?

If not can they be added?

If they are, then what are the requirements for them being displayed in the Careers site?

Comment: It's unfortunate that this question haven't received enough popularity. People who participate mostly on sites other than Stack Overflow receive misleading top tags in their Careers profile. For example, according to Careers top tags, I'm a PHP programmer, which has **nothing to do** with my real profile, which would rather be defined through tags such as *programming-practices*, *interview*, *testing*, *development-process*, *coding-style*, *code-quality*, etc. from Programmers.SE.